# Combine filter complex

Tags: video

I have two commands who works fine, but when i try to combine them they didn't work.

```
... -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=200:200:60:30,boxblur=10[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=60:30[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a  ......

.... -vf drawtext="fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/webcore/comic.ttf: text='text here': x=(main_w/2-text_w/2): y=main_h-(text_h*2): fontsize=20: fontcolor=white" ........
```

please do not refer to other pages because i already tried everything and nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to write the text upon the final result, use

```
-filter_complex "[0:v]crop=200:200:60:30,boxblur=10[fg];[0:v][fg]overlay=60:30,drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/webcore/comic.ttf: text='www.ffstream.com':x=(main_w/2-text_w/2):y=main_h-(text_h*2):fontsize=20:fontcolor=white[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a  ......
```